# Ksh/Bash History for jailed SSH users

Tags: shell, ssh, command-history, openssh, chroot

How can I keep a history of activities for chroot'd SSH (not SFTP) users?
I've tried:

- created a .sh_history in their home with the proper permissions
- created a custom $HISTFILE in .profile and in its jailed /etc/profile
- exported HISTFILE after logging in.

This is how my Match in sshd_config is:

```
Match Group sshuser
            ChrootDirectory %h
            AllowTcpForwarding no
```